# Firefox: libicui18n.so.58 cannot open shared object file

Tags: firefox, manjaro

I just installed a fresh os with manjaro Linux i3-wm edition.

I couldn't find Firefox by default so I installed it via pacman.

Now when I run the `Firefox` command I get back:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried searching your system (using mlocate for example) for libxul.so? I have 2 Firefox derivative installed on my Arch system and each of them has that file installed at a different location than the path you gave.

Comment: I get back: locate: can not stat () '/var/lib/mlocate.db' : No such file or directory

Comment: It sounds like it's installed but has never been updated. Try running `updatedb` followed by `locate libxul.so`

Comment: From my previous comment, `updatedb` must be run as root/sudo but `locate` does not. Are you using the standard Firefox from the official Arch repositories, installed by `sudo pacman -Syu firefox` or from a GUI front end to the official repositories and not something from the AUR?

Comment: I ran the command but still same problem. I'm using whatever was default on pacman.

Comment: That's weird.  Does it find `libxul.so` anywhere when you run `locate libxul.so`? If so, a hack fix would be to symlink wherever it is to `/usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so`.

Answer (score 2):

Above comments offer no help because they don't know well about Archlinux (yes Manjaro is based on Archlinux).

The cause of this issue is Archlinux's rolling update, while Firefox is still using the old version of `icu`, this package has been updated in Archlinux's upstream, so Firefox failed to find `libicui18n.so.58`, which is provided by version 58 of `icu`.

So in order to fix it, just install the old version from AUR via `yaourt` or any tool you like. In your case, [`icu58`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icu58/) is needed.

And next time you come across the same error, first you should find out which package does the library belongs to, then try to install the required version of that package. In this case, `pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libicui18n.so` should tell you `icu` own that library, the `.58` after `.so` tells you the required version is 58, then you can go straight to AUR to find that package.

PS: the version number is likely to change over time. I just tested and it tells `*.so.59` not found.